# Button onClick() does not load the myClickHandlermethod defined in the custom class HttpExampleActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Code for activity_main.xml:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.android.httptry.MainActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/myUrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:text="@string/button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:onClick="myClickHandler"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Code for the HttpExampleActivity.java:

```
public class HttpExampleActivity extends Activity {
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
private EditText urlText;
private TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
}

// When user clicks button, calls AsyncTask.

public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    // Gets the URL from the UI's text field.
    String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
    } else {
        textView.setText("No network connection available.");
    }
}

private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}


// Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

}

On checking the logcat, I found the following error message:

```
Process: com.example.android.httptry, PID: 29936


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method myClickHandler(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
```

I'm fairly new to android development so couldn't understand why despite naming the onClick() method I was getting the above error. Any solutions to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is silly, but it happened to me once, I was missing the **android:clickable="true"**

Comment: i guess that's true by default for a button, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
tools:context="com.example.android.httptry.MainActivity"
```

to

```
tools:context="com.yourpackage.HttpExampleActivity"
```

or define the `myClickHandler` method in your `com.example.android.httptry.MainActivity` class (if there is any such class)

The stack trace that you've shared clearly indicates that 
it's looking for a `myClickHandler(View)` method defined in the context that's given which is `com.example.android.httptry.MainActivity` in this case but there's no such method defined in that activity.

It's in the `HttpExampleActivity`.

So, that makes it all clear, either you change the context or define such method in the context class.

Comment: the tools:context make no issue for click as you said.

Comment: it will definitely make, java is looking for myClickHandler(View) method defined in the context that's given which is `com.example.android.httptry.MainActivity` in this case but there's no such method defined in that activity. It's in the `HttpExampleActivity`. The error that @sshashankk has shared makes it all clear!

Comment: @AshishRanjan The errors persist despite changing the context to HttpExampleActivity

Comment: did you write it in the correct format, i.e, with the package name like : `com.yourpackage.HttpExampleActivity`